# React Native Firebase storage - issues uploading images to storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, image, react-native, firebase-storage

I have tried uploading images to my bucket in firebase storage, I wasted a massive amount of time on this and tried all the available tutorials in the subject but nothing worked.

For some reason when I create a reference to the storage and execute the "putFile" method and supply the local path of the image from the emulator, it does not upload and does not execute anything.

I am not getting any response from the puFile promise, not in the 'then' and not in the 'catch' statements.

This is the function with which I upload to firebase storage.

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage'

uploadFile = async (path, imageName) => {     
            await storage().ref(imageName).putFile(path).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err)) ;     
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you aren't getting a response from `then`/`catch`, that implies that other parts of that line are causing a syntax error. I would expect that `uploadFile(path, imageName).catch(err => console.error(err))` may show something. You could also add in `console.log({ path, imageName })` and make sure their values are what you expect.

Comment: I removed all the console.log from the function to clean it up but I did it for the arguments. In regards to the "uploadFile" there is no such function under storage().
The URL looks as follows: file:///data/user/0/com.joyride_client/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_497bc282-50b3-4406-962f-d98821e752e8.jpg

Comment: `UploadFile` is the name of **your** function, so use that line wherever you are calling it.

Comment: Nothing is returned when I call the function from the outside. I think its the connection to firebase somehow but I can't find the issue.